# What does "hit the tiz-own" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english, phrases

I've come across it in the 14th episode of the 3rd season of *The Office*. Here is the context:

> Andy: Just listen, I forgot to tell you the plan for this Saturday. You, me, bars, beers, buzzed. Wings. Shots. Drunk. Waitresses, hot. Football – Cornell/Hofstra. Slaughter. Then a quick nap at my place and we’ll **hit the tiz-own**.

Comment: maybe town? just a wild guess though

Comment: Seems to  be slang for 'town'. Possible Hispanic, Black, or rap connection - "Orlando and Penelope Cruz on the Tizown" - "Thats know for tearin up you tizown. Spray the hood up" "San Diego tizown to the LBC Compton and South Central to the SMB"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an example of what is called [-iz- cant](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-iz-#English).  [**Cant**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cant_(language)) itself is a way of altering language within a particular group so that it is harder to understand by people outside that group. [Pig Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) is a particularly well-known type of cant.

From the Wiktionary link above, we see that the **-iz-** pattern (and its relative, **-izzle**) was cant among Black Americans in the 1970s and was popularized to the general public by the rapper Snoop Dogg in the late 1980s.

Structurally, **-iz-** is an [infix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix) that follows either the first syllable or the first phoneme of a word (the first three examples are from the Wiktionary entry, the fourth is your example from "The Office"):

> ‎shit + ‎-iz- → ‎shiznit
>
> house + ‎-iz- → ‎hizouse
>
> damn + ‎-iz- → ‎dizamn
>
> town + -iz- → tizown

You should not copy this usage unless you are a late-20th-century rapper.  Part of the humor of the context of this usage in "The Office" is that Andy, a white character with a privileged background (there is a running joke that he brings up his Cornell University education as often as possible), is using outdated African-American "street" vernacular. The impression you're meant to get is that he is trying to be "cool", but failing miserably and only looking foolish.

Finally, it's important to understanding this that you know that [**hit the town**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hit%20the%20town) is an expression meaning, "go out and have fun at restaurants, bars, or nightclubs."